# Как поменять иконку приложения?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qmake

Собственно вот цитата из документации:

> First, put a single line of text to the myapp.rc file:
>
> IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE     "myappico.ico"

может я неправильно понимаю выражение `single line`, но файл `.rc` содержащий одну эту строку выдает ошибку

```
Start tag exepted
```

Помещение этого же выражение меж строк

```
 <!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
     IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "icon.ico"
</RCC>
```

Так же выдает ошибку:

```
Unexpected text
```

Так куда же вставить мне эту строку чтоб поменять иконку?

**UPD:**
мой работающий файл ресурсов имеет вид:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource prefix="/">
...
        <file>qml/main.qml</file>
...
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

И попытки вставить строку в него так же провалились с теми же ошибками.

**UPD:**
А вот как добавляю `rc` к проекту:

```
set(RESOURCES
    resources/resources.qrc
    resources/proj.rc
)

qt5_add_resources (QRC_SOURCES ${RESOURCES})

...

add_executable( proj_name
...
    ${QRC_SOURCES}
...)
```

и пробовала просто новый `projname.rc` туда же добавить.

Comment: Какая версия студии? Те RC-файлы что у меня есть не используют XML-формат.

Comment: студия 15, документация по которой пытаюсь сделать - qt (и собственно приложение у меня qt-qml). У меня уже есть ресурсный файл, работает хорошо, но в нем формат как во втором моем примере. С тэгами <>.

Comment: Версию студии в вопрос впишите. Самый простой вариант - имеющийся у вас корректный RC-файл модифицировать попробуйте.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в свой файл эту строку я уже во все места пыталась вставить, выдает ровно ту же ошибку - неожиданный текст и отсутствие стартового тэга. Отдельный файл я создала чтоб уж точно соответствовать документации. Не думаю что студия тут имеет значение, так как собираю я смаке-ом qt приложение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот такого rc файла должно быть достаточно для иконки приложения:

```
0                  ICON           "myappico.ico"
```

---

Допустим, Ваш rc файл имеете имя resources.rc, тогда cmake код будет выглядеть так:

```
set(RESOURCES
    resources/resources.qrc
)

qt5_add_resources (QRC_SOURCES ${RESOURCES})

...

add_executable( proj_name
...
    ${QRC_SOURCES}
    resources.rc
...)
```

resources.rc это специфичный для windows файл, поэтому его нужно напрямую с исходниками передавать в `add_executable`, для него не нужно и нельзя выполнять никакой предобработки.

Comment: Та же ошибка - Start tag exepted

Comment: @Mira, покажите как Вы скармливаете rc файл компилятору

Comment: добавила в вопрос

Comment: @Mira, это qrc файл, а где rc файл?

Comment: .rc файл отдельный там же добавляла, следующей строкой за .qrc. никакой разницы в поведении компилятора - ругается одинаково вне зависимости от разрешения )

Comment: @Mira, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! помогло с ошибкой компиляции! правда иконка на окошке не поменялась(а приложения - да), но я сейчас попробую qico.dll закинуть рядом. И такой вопрос - а добавленная так иконка вкомпилируется в проект? (не надо будет ее рядом с приложение подкладывать?)

Comment: @Mira, да, она внедряется в исполняемый файл, ничего хранить не нужно. Если нет иконки при запуске, то скорее всего какой-то глюк, никакого qico.dll не надо докладывать. Попробуйте ещё раз запустить, может exlplorer закэшировал старую иконку

Comment: @Mira, или Вы имеет ввиду не поменялась у окна иконка? Если так, то окну нужно явно выставить иконку с помощью `setWindowIcon` и уже ресурсов qrc

Comment: Так и делаю, видимо у меня этот случай http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587359/qapplicationsetwindowicon-works-on-windows-xp-but-does-not-work-on-windows-7 , dll-ка ищется ) Не поможет - задам еще вопрос )

Comment: @Mira, да, для подсистемы Qt нужно qico.dll, я просто сначала подумал, что у Вас у бинарника есть иконка, а в панеле задач у приложения — нет. Для бинарника не нужна это dll, а для использования в приложении qt, из qrc ресурсов, нужна

Comment: Небольшое уточнение: строку надо использовать именно IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE (из документации). Она все ставит корректно (без доп ухищрений). А из вашего ответа - только значок исполняемого файла меняет, окошка - никак, (хоть куда подкладывай dll.)

Comment: @Mira, значит что-то не так делаете. Я же не придумал эту строчку. Всё должно работать, если делаете правильно.

Comment: Так я тоже не придумала свою ), это из документации и работает верно у меня. Ну ладно, кто будет искать - сам выберет, какая у него работает.

Answer (score 1):

Дополню [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494130/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/494135#494135) @ixSci

Для `qmake` нужно в `.pro` файл добавить:

```
RC_FILE = app.rc
OTHER_FILES += app.rc
```

Пример [app.rc](https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager/blob/master/app.rc)